# I am unable to enter logic code to enter pin number in dynamic textfield.Using Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to enter pin number in dynamic text field. Pin number text field changes every time the website is loaded. Need help to write logic for entering the  pin number in 3 text field. There is 4 pin number but I get option to enter pin number in 3 text field.

[image: enclosed image of screenshot and code]

[Screenshot and code reference](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/36346/35535)

Comment: Hi Narendra I have added link and image of detail code. can you please help with code

Comment: @DebanjanB, Thanks for faith in me. :)

Comment: @BaluriAR Update the question with the text based _HTML_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your posted HTML. you can try with indexes if its same type of field.

Use below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(1)")).sendKeys("your value"); // for first text box

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("your value"); // for Second text box

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(3)")).sendKeys("your value"); // for third text box
```

Please change the `index` in  `div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(index)` as per textbox in page UI position.

**UPDATE**

If you are not sure which textbox have to accept value then use below logic

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   // first you need to store your testdata in a collection 

    Map<String,String> pinCodes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    pinCodes.put("pin1", "2");
    pinCodes.put("pin2", "3");
    pinCodes.put("pin3", "3");
    pinCodes.put("pin4", "4");

    // you can remove the values as per you need suppose you only want `pin1` `pin2` then remove  `pinCodes.put("pin3", "3");` and `pinCodes.put("pin4", "4");` from above code

      enterPinCode(pincodes); //call method to enter the values in corresponding text-boxes 
}

public void enterPinCode(Map<String,String> pinCodes) {

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : pinCodes.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            switch (key) {
                case "pin1" :
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(1)")).sendKeys(value);
                    break;
                case "pin2" :
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys(value);
                    break;
                case "pin3" :
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(3)")).sendKeys(value);
                    break;
                case "pin4" :
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input.input-pin:nth-child(4)")).sendKeys(value);
                    break;

                default :
                    System.out.println("pincode textbox key not found");
                    break;
            }

        }
}
```

OR if checkbox are dynamic on webpage then replace below code in `switch` statement :

```
switch (key) {
    case "pin1" :
        List<WebElement> box1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input[placeholder='1st']"));
        if(!box1.isEmpty()) {
            box1.get(0).sendKeys(value);
        }
        break;

    case "pin2" :
        List<WebElement> box2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input[placeholder='2nd']"));
        if(!box2.isEmpty()) {
            box2.get(0).sendKeys(value);
        }
    break;

    case "pin3" :
        List<WebElement> box3 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input[placeholder='3rd']"));
        if(!box3.isEmpty()) {
            box3.get(0).sendKeys(value);
        }
    break;

    case "pin4" :
        List<WebElement> box4 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='field-set'] input[placeholder='4th']"));
        if(!box4.isEmpty()) {
            box4.get(0).sendKeys(value);
        }
    break;

    default :
        System.out.println("pincode textbox key not found");
    break;
}
```

This code will send the pin-code in corresponding pin-code textbox if available on webpage.

Comment: The above code works but I need to enter pin number in 3 text field. As it is dynamic website the pin text field changes every time. For example I need to enter PIN 1 , PIN 3,PIN 4 or 1,2,3 or 4,3,1 I need to write Java logic to excute the PIN number.

Comment: @BaluriAR, updated the answer. let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: _pin text field changes every time_  you mean number of textbox on webpage getting change. sometime it shows only 2 textboxes or some time 4. is it like that ? or the element ids are getting change ?

Comment: it has 3 textboxes, but the element ids are getting changed. for screenshot please click on Screenshot and code reference link mentioned above.

Comment: There is nothing to do with dynamic ids. i have used different locator. Is updated answer not working for you ?

Comment: @BaluriAR, try recent updated code. hope this will help